# Regex to allow all Numbers but not if only 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to figure out how to return true if any number but not if only 0 or contains any decimal `.` that is

```
1    //true
23   //true
10   //true
0.2  //false
10.2 //false
02   //false
0    //false
```

I have made this regex so far and it's working fine but it also allows 0 which I don't want

```
/^[0-9]+$/.test(value);
```

I tried to search my best and tried these regex so far but failed

```
/^[0]*[0-9]+$/
/^[0-9]+[^0]*$/
```

I am not good in regex at all. Thank you anticipation.

Comment: Isn't `02` the same thing as `2` in terms of numbers? Why do you make a distinction?

Comment: Yes in terms of numbers but because as a string 02 is different from 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were close: `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`.

The leading `[1-9]` forces the number to have a most-significant digit which is not `0`, so `0` will not be accepted. After that, any digit can come.

Finally, a number containing `.` is not accepted.

Comment: Thanks Stefano. That worked great. I once thought about it but couldn't understand how it will allow 10 if [1-9].

Comment: `10` is recognized by `[1-9][0-9]` (one repetition of `[0-9]*`), since `1` is in range `1-9` and 0 in range `0-9`.

Comment: how will it be applicable for 3 digit ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead at the start.

```
/^(?!0)\d+$/.test(value);
```

This regex won't match the string if it contain 0 at the start.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. What if I don't want to allow 02 as well?

Comment: then try `/^(?!0)\d+$/.test(value);` . THis won't allow 0 to be present at the start.

Comment: Your name is a *quasi*-anagram of "Vanish Raja". Also, the regex `/^[1-9]+$/` accomplishes the same and is easier to read. Not to mention shorter.

Comment: but it won't allow `10`

Comment: Then `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/` is the answer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel have something to tell about my name? :)

Comment: @AmitJoki The intention isn't to bad-mouth his name. If you notice, AvinashRaj's image is a ninja. "Vanish Raja" would be a very suitable name. Because ninjas vanish... That's why. And no, I have no 'anagram' for your name. At least for now. But your name sounds like you are saying "Ah mate, jokin' ".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I knew that your intention wasn't to bad-mouth his name :)  That's a good one too :)

Comment: @AmitJoki Sorry for the misinterpretation. It really sounded like you were offended. My intention really isn't to offend anyone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a regex. Just make use of `Number` function or `+` unary operator to convert it into an actual number and see if it's less than `1` and greater than `-1`

```
value = +value; // it's now a number
var bool = value < 1 && value > -1;  // less than 1 but greater than -1
```

Comment: I don't know who down voted but yes may be because there is no regex while the question is about regex.

Comment: regex isn't needed here and is actually a bit overkill. So posted a non-regex solution.

Comment: This is perfectly valid answer +1

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateNumber(yournumber){
return (parseFloat(yournumber ) == parseInt(yournumber) &&  parseInt(yournumber))
}
```

Comment: Sorry I want to do it with regex.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work with all digits except 0 but 00 will work

```
/([0-9]{2,})|[1-9]/.test(value);
```